# Reuse wrapped socket streams for RSA and then AES encryption

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, stream

Rather than encrypting data myself and writing it to/reading it from buffered streams, I want to open a CipherOutputStream/CipherInputStream with RSA keys (client has public, server has private).

However, I want to be able to start using an AES key that is decided on through the RSA encrypted connection with the cipher streams rather than the RSA key. As the cipher streams have no way of changing which cipher is used in the encryption/decryption, is there a way to reclaim the socket streams from the wrapped cipher streams and then wrap them with another cipher stream that has the AES key?

Comment: As long you don't explicitly close the CipherInputStream then the wrapped InputStream will not be closed. Therefore you can create another `CipherInputStream(s.getInputStream())`, where `s` is your socket

Comment: You could also try reinitializing the underlying `Cipher` object, but the problem will have with all of this is (a) synchronizing with the peer and (b) getting to the end of the old cipher before switching to the new one. Is there a reason you aren't using SSL?